# Pseudo 3d effect with CSS transforms?

Tags: css, 3d, css-transforms

I have a `div` containing small `div`'s that each have a `background-image` of a colored ball:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="ball" style="left: 100px; top: 50px;">
  <div class="ball" style="left: 120px; top: 100px;">
  <div class="ball" style="left: 140px; top: 150px;">
  <div class="ball" style="left: 160px; top: 200px;">
  <div class="ball" style="left: 180px; top: 250px;">
</div>
```

Now I would like to create some sort of pseudo 3D effect, where the balls that have a smaller value of 'top' are smaller , and balls that are more near the bottom appear larger.

I've read some bits about CSS3 transforms and perspective, but I have no idea how to do it.

Is there any way to adjust the `width` and `height` of `div`'s , based on its `top`-property ?

Comment: How about something like [that](https://jsfiddle.net/5g205zub/)?

Comment: Thank you, but the balls also can change positions, so the size really has to depend on the top-property...

Comment: @Dylan Does my answer work for you?

Comment: @Dylan With CSS you can't grab the value of a property like that. Use Javascript instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable to store top value in css like this `style="--top: 10px"` and use it later like this `var(--top)`.

**Update**

You need to use JavaScript to set the `--top` property using `setProperty` method and you can get the value of `--top` using `getPropertyValue` method. See the example for dynamically changing `--top` onclick event which changes the `--top` value and `width` and `height` are adjusted automatically.

**Code Snippet**

```js
balls = document.getElementsByClassName('ball');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(balls, function(ball){
 ball.onclick = function() {
  ball.style.setProperty('--top', parseInt(ball.style.getPropertyValue('--top')) * 1.2 + 'px')
  }
})
```

```css
.ball {
    background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Soccer_ball.svg);
    width: calc(var(--top) * 1.2);
    height: calc(var(--top) * 1.2);
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ball" style="left: 100px; --top: 50px;"></div>
  <div class="ball" style="left: 120px; --top: 100px;"></div>
  <div class="ball" style="left: 140px; --top: 150px;"></div>
  <div class="ball" style="left: 160px; --top: 200px;"></div>
  <div class="ball" style="left: 180px; --top: 250px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the top-property needs to be dynamically set. So unless there is a way to keep the --top variable in sync with the real top property, this is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a real 3d transform on the containing element:

```css
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
  perspective: 300px;
}

.inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transform:  rotateX(60deg);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    border: solid 2px green;
}

.ball {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: absolute;
    transform:  rotateX(-60deg);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="inner">
  <div class="ball" style="left: 100px; top: 50px;"></div>
  <div class="ball" style="left: 120px; top: 100px;"></div>
  <div class="ball" style="left: 140px; top: 150px;"></div>
  <div class="ball" style="left: 160px; top: 200px;"></div>
  <div class="ball" style="left: 180px; top: 250px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```